# Removing duplicate key but unique rows with priority using SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, duplicates, yahoo-finance

I'm quite new to Python and I'm trying to get the following done:

1. Pull RSS feed from Yahoo Finance News API ->[YDN](http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/company.html)
2. Put the Title, Link,PubDate into a Database table
3. Store only unique Titles and the latest PubDate

1 and 2 I got through no problem but when I try to do 3, I ran into some trouble.
The following is how the table looks like:

[image]

As you can see, I have duplicated Titles with different PubDate. What I've been trying to do is to follow the steps ilustrated from Microsoft Kb -> [Support Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444).

I was able to get through steps 1 - 3 which does:

1. Selecting all Titles with counts > 1 into a table called holdkey
2. Selecting all distinct records with Titles equal to Titles in the holdkey table

my code is slightly different from what was shown in the MSFT link:

```
import sqlite3

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('''create table holdkey as 
            select Title,count(*) 
            from bar group by Title
            having count(*)>1''')
cur.execute('''create table holdup as 
            select distinct bar.* 
            from bar, holdkey 
            where bar.Title = holdkey.Title''')
```

What I need help on is that in my holdup table (as seen in the screenshot), I still get duplicate Titles because the pubDate is different and that it is known as distinct by SQLite. Is there a way to delete the duplicates based on the PubDate?

I would ideally just keep the latest one, but getting rid of the duplicate is more important.

Let me know if more clarification is required. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT b.symbol, b.title, b.link, b.pubdate
  FROM bar b JOIN
(
  SELECT title, MAX(pubdate) pubdate
    FROM bar
   GROUP BY title
) q ON b.title = q.title 
   AND b.pubdate = q.pubdate
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/affa6/7)** demo

Comment: Thank you for the answer. From my understanding, this is a two step query where you first SELECT the tile and max date into the table q and then using an inner join to find only the records that match pubDate and Title in bar. Is that right? So I could use this statement to get only the max date after I've removed the duplicates.

Comment: Yes there are two steps in the process of executing this query: 1) get unique title with max pub date, 2) join back on title and pubdate to grab other columns. That is a general approach. Now if symbol, title, and link are always the same per title then you can do it in one go.

Comment: I tried it out and realize I could have different links to the same table...How do I go about doing that? I suppose you cannot use Max() on a string

Comment: Can you edit question and post some relevant sample data in textual form or edit my sqlfiddle example and post the new link after you hit `Build Schema`? That way it'll be much easier.

Comment: No worries, I've added an extra step to group by title and insert them back to the original table ! Thanks though, I will accept your answer!